# Check whether Enum contains string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have

```
Enum eNUM
{
     one,Two,Three
}
```

I have a UserDefinedString . For example: `Four`
I want to check whether user defined string present in `eNUm`. I tried with

```
eNUM _num;
if (Enum.TryParse<eNUM>("UserDefinedString", out _num))
{
   //do some thing 
}
```

I also tried:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(eNUM), "UserDefinedString"))
```

This is not working for me

Comment: `Enum.IsDefined` will return true if string exits in Enum. What you mean by `not working`?

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not working for me"? Do you get an error?  Is the result different than you expect? If so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example works:

```
if (Enum.TryParse<eNUM>("Four", out _num))
{
   //do some thing 
}
else
{
   // invalid enum value
}
```

When calling this with `Four`, you will get in the `else` branch. When calling with `Two` it works.

If you want to ignore the casing, you can set the second parameter of `TryParse` to `true`.

Comment: @Singh: You are welcome. Since you are new here, don't forget to mark one of the answer if that answer answered your question best.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is an **exact** match when trying to parse. You can make life easier by forcing case before comparison if you know your enum only contains lower-case values, for example:

```
Enum eNUM
{
    one, two, three ...
}

...

eNUM num;
string findThisValue = "OnE"; // Odd casing...
if (Enum.TryParse(findThisValue.ToLower(), out num))
{
    // Do something with num
}
```

Comment: indeed it may be best to make the enums all upper or lower case then ToLower() before the TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(eNUM));
```

this will get you all values in the enum as string, then you can check for your key using linq function like Contains or Any